# convert text to table in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

i'm trying to convert a pdf document to a pandas dataframe.

I was able to extract the pdf to a text but not sure how to get the below desired values in the text file to a dictionary

so far i have used the below code to extract pdf to text as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfplumber

data = './data/coc.pdf'

with pdfplumber.open(data) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

print(text)
```

Below is the text file

```
" \n \nCertificate of Currency \nXYZ Limited \nABN 121011100 54720   AFSL 232111 \n \nAs at Date \n2 November 2015 \nPolicy Information \nPolicy Type \nProfessional  \n \n \nInsured \nUniversity of ABC and others as defined by the policy \ndocument. \n \nInsurer \nMMO Limited   \n                                                    \nPolicy Number(s) \L0K107721013  \n \nPeriod of Insurance \nFrom 4.00pm 1/11/2015 to 4.00pm 1/11/2016 \n \nInterest Insured \nLoss incurred as a result of a civil liability claim made against the insured \nbased solely on the insured’s provision of their professional services  \n \nLimit of Liability \n$20,000,000 any one claim and $60,000,000 in the aggregate for all claims "
```

Now I like to convert the text file to a dictionary. How can I update the code below with an if condition to create a dictionary that will have key:value pair based on \n or \n\n

```
d = dict([i.splitlines() for i in text.split('\n\n')])
```

I get the below error:

Error:dictionary update sequence element:

[image]

**Please find attached desired output table:**

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Also add the code you tried, and mention the exact point where you got stuck..

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. It involves high complexity. Please break down your problem and try solving it one by one. We have been trying to solve this for the past 3 years. We have only reached around 90% accuracy.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I have added the code which works for me. I do not know how to approach the next steps

Comment: @Vishnudev I have defined the problem statement as Problem 1, 2, 3 in the post.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will not get an answer here @Jasmeen. Your questions are too broad. For example: To get the values for policy period, you need to identify that section of text and then use date extractors in that section. Use regex to extract data.

Comment: @Vishnudev what about Problem 2 and Problem 3

Comment: Same. Use regex @Jasmeen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated answer**

I did some changes to actually make it easier to do, and to make it obivous how to actually find values.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime


def clean_text(text) -> list:
    """Removes empty lines as well as leading and trailing spaces.
    Also removes EOL characters.

    Args:
        text (str/list): Input text

    Returns:
        (list): A list of strings
    """
    if type(text) == str:
        splittext = text.splitlines()
        if len(splittext) == 1:
            print("Text is a single line string")
            return text
    elif type(text) == list:
        splittext = text
    result = []
    for line in splittext:
        cleaned = line.strip()
        if cleaned != "":
            result.append(cleaned)
    return result


filename = 'text_sample1.txt'
with open(filename) as infile:
    text = infile.read()



uncleaned_sections = text.split('\n \n')
sections = []
for section in uncleaned_sections:
    sections.append(clean_text(section.splitlines()))

for secindex, section in enumerate(sections):
    for lineindex, line in enumerate(section):
        print(f'sections[{secindex}][{lineindex}]: {line}')


# with the above, we have sections of data, instead of a block of data
# this means we can change the way we deal with it

# we should have 7 sections, provided that all input files are structured
# in the same way
assert(len(sections) == 7)


pd_dt = datetime.strptime(sections[1][1], '%d %B %Y')
policy_date = f'{pd_dt.day:02}/{pd_dt.month:02}/{pd_dt.year}'
abn = sections[0][2].split('ABN ')[1].split('AFSL')[0].strip()
policy_number = sections[3][3]
period_start = sections[4][1].split("From ")[1].split(" to ")[0].split(' ')[1]
period_end = sections[4][1].split(" to ")[1].split(' ')[1]
insured = ' '.join(sections[2][1:])
insurer = sections[3][1]
interest_insured = ' '.join(sections[5][1:])

as_dict = {
    'Date': policy_date,
    'ABN': abn,
    'Policy Number': policy_number,
    'Period Start': period_start,
    'Period End': period_end,
    'Insured': insured,
    'Insurer': insurer,
    'Interest Insured': interest_insured
}

pprint(as_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sections[0][0]: Certificate of Currency
sections[0][1]: XYZ Limited
sections[0][2]: ABN 121 011100 54720   AFSL 81141141
sections[1][0]: As at Date
sections[1][1]: 2 November 2015
sections[1][2]: Policy Information
sections[1][3]: Policy Type
sections[1][4]: Professional
sections[2][0]: Insured
sections[2][1]: University of ABC and others as defined by the policy
sections[2][2]: document.
sections[3][0]: Insurer
sections[3][1]: MMO Limited
sections[3][2]: Policy Number(s)
sections[3][3]: L0K107721013
sections[4][0]: Period of Insurance
sections[4][1]: From 4.00pm 1/11/2015 to 4.00pm 1/11/2016
sections[5][0]: Interest Insured
sections[5][1]: Loss incurred as a result of a civil liability claim made against the insured
sections[5][2]: based solely on the insured’s provision of their professional services
sections[6][0]: Limit of Liability
sections[6][1]: $20,000,000 any one claim and $60,000,000 in the aggregate for all claims
sections[6][2]: during the period of insurance. (Subject to the reinstatement provisions of
sections[6][3]: the policy).
sections[6][4]: ABN 121 011100 54720
{'ABN': '121 011100 54720',
 'Date': '02/11/2015',
 'Insured': 'University of ABC and others as defined by the policy document.',
 'Insurer': 'MMO Limited',
 'Interest Insured': 'Loss incurred as a result of a civil liability claim '
                     'made against the insured based solely on the insured’s '
                     'provision of their professional services',
 'Period End': '1/11/2016',
 'Period Start': '1/11/2015',
 'Policy Number': 'L0K107721013'}
```

---

**NOTE: PREVIOUS ANSWER**

This answer is for the previous iteration of the question :-/

---

You need to process the lines in the text and find the correct lines to extract the data you need.

I've provided examples on how to find the values you listed in your problems. I advise you to check w3schools for the basic string methods I used...

[string.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
[string.splitlines()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_splitlines.asp)
[string.strip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp)
[f-strings (I really like f-strings)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

The code below should be enough to get you started...

**CODE**

```py
def clean_text(text: str) -> list:
    """Removes empty lines as well as leading and trailing spaces.
    Also removes EOL characters.

    Args:
        text (str): Input text

    Returns:
        (list): A list of strings
    """
    splittext = text.splitlines()
    if len(splittext) == 1:
        print("Text is a single line string")
        return text
    result = []
    for line in splittext:
        cleaned = line.strip()
        if cleaned != "":
            result.append(cleaned)
    return result


text = " \n \nCertificate of Currency \nXYZ Limited \nABN 121011100 54720   AFSL 232111 \n \nAs at Date \n2 November 2015 \nPolicy Information \nPolicy Type \nProfessional  \n \n \nInsured \nUniversity of ABC and others as defined by the policy \ndocument. \n \nInsurer \nMMO Limited   \n                                                    \nPolicy Number(s) \L0K107721013  \n \nPeriod of Insurance \nFrom 4.00pm 1/11/2015 to 4.00pm 1/11/2016 \n \nInterest Insured \nLoss incurred as a result of a civil liability claim made against the insured \nbased solely on the insured’s provision of their professional services  \n \nLimit of Liability \n$20,000,000 any one claim and $60,000,000 in the aggregate for all claims "
text = clean_text(text)
# I alsways add this when using the 'previous_line' method below
# it can reduce failures
text.append('')


previous_line = ""
for line in text:
    # two \ needed due to it being a special character in strings
    if "Policy Number(s)" in previous_line:
        policy_number = line
    elif "From " in line and "Period of Insurance" in previous_line:
        # this is a secondary check for the start/end dates
        # Just in case another line in the text contains 'From '
        start = line.split("From ")[1].split(" to ")[0]
        end = line.split(" to ")[1]
    elif "ABN " and "AFSL " in line:
        # using different method than the splits above
        abn_split = line.split()
        abn_value = f"{abn_split[1]} {abn_split[2]}"

    previous_line = line

# Some try/except blocks to check if the values have been found
try:
    print(f"Start: {start}\nEnd: {end}")
except NameError as e:
    print("Start/End dates not found")

try:
    print(f"ABN: {abn_value}")
except NameError as e:
    print("ABN not found")

try:
    print(f"Policy Number: {policy_number}")
except NameError as e:
    print("Policy number not found")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Start: 4.00pm 1/11/2015
End: 4.00pm 1/11/2016
ABN: 121011100 54720
Policy Number: L0K107721013
```

Comment: note, whether or not this holds up depends on whether the PDF files you're processing actually match the `text` sample provided...

Comment: I get an error NameError: name 'policy_number' is not defined. I doubled check the text file and the code and couldn't find any issue. Any ideas why the error

Comment: that could be due to copying/pasting of the text from *your* IDE to SO and then from SO to *my* IDE. For example, tabs can be converted to spaces. I slightly edited the code for the line to check the policy number...

Comment: To expand on that, text processing is extremely dependent on the source of the text. Since PDF processing is not 100% perfect, as mentioned by other SO members, you need to find the sweet spot to ensure proper processing and actually finding the values you need. This really depends on how well the PDFs you're processing are created and interpreted...

Comment: I've added some example try/except blocks to determine if what you needed was found

Comment: Sure. Just not able to figure out why policy_number is not defined.

Comment: I tried the new code and get IndexError: list index out of range. Could you guide me how I can troubleshoot this error please.

Comment: So, we immediately have an example of what can make text processing slightly frustrating. Can you add a `print(line)` directly below the `if` to find the policy number? I'm guessing in this case the \ is not present...

Comment: When i add print(line) below if, i get Policy Number(s) in output

Comment: So that means you have to check the `previous_line` value for `Policy Number(s)` instead of the current line. I've added a helper method which I used in one of my previous projects to make it easier to deal with text. It simply removes potential irritating factors.

Comment: I have upload the coc.txt file here on a temp storage  https://tmpfiles.org/dl/74576/coc.text

Comment: That's usefull. If you have a second example, could you provide that as well?

Comment: That's working perfectly. So if i have to include new values (like Insured, Insurer ) in the if conditions how do i add them. cannot we have a generalised if condition which checks for \n or \n\n. Finally how create a dictionary {"ABN": "121 011100 54720", "Policy Number":"L0K107721013"}

Comment: that was a good suggestion, run the code above and you can see this actually makes it easier to map. It does require the same structure for ALL pdfs you are processing...

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are indeed somewhat broad but if I understood correctly, your main problem is to get the table(s) in the PDF to Pandas dataframe and you formulated the problems in the question after managing to read the PDF as text. However, I think it's easier to just use tabula and let that directly parse the PDF to Pandas dataframe.

Install tabula:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

Using tabula:

```
import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf("myfile.pdf", pages='all')
# Note that dfs is list of dataframes, the tables found in the PDF.
```

And there you go. Rest of your problems are related to Pandas and I suggest you either search answers in Pandas docs/forums or ask a separate question about how to process the dataframe(s).

Note that PDF processing is never 100% accurate due to that PDFs are inherently not meant to be interpreted by machines. This solution may or may not work depending on the PDF. For me, it did work with a similar problem.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but the query is to take specific fields and their values from the pdf and convert to table. Here is the flow pdf_source>convert_to_txt>read_fields_from_text>create_dictionary_field_value_pair>convert_to_dataframe